# How to get ad slot by slot name

Tags: google-dfp

I'm using DFP to show ads on a web page.
Is there any way to refer to particular ad slot by name? e.g. `googletag.getSlotByName('abc')`
My intension is to refresh ads in particular slots.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The `pubads.defineSlot` method returns a reference to the slot. This reference can be saved in a variable so you can use it later to refresh it. This would be an example:

```
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    var slotABC = googletag.defineSlot("/12345678/SLotABC", [728, 90],
    "div-gpt-ad-1327312723268-0").addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.enableServices();
    googletag.display("div-gpt-ad-1327312723268-0");

    //Then you can refer to it and refresh it like this:
    googletag.pubads().refresh([slotABC]);
})
```

More info: [here](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/3058726?hl=en)